# Valgrind "Invalid write of size n" when using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, struct, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm creating a graph using this structures

```
struct node
{
  int id;
  struct node *ad;
};

struct graph
{
  int numVert;
  struct node **adjList;
  int *visited;
  int *back;
};
```

And using this to allocate the memory

```
static struct graph *graph_create(struct world *W, int v)
{
  struct graph *G = NULL;

  if ((G = graph_alloc(v)) != NULL)
  {
    /* some stuff */
  }

  return G;
}

static struct graph *graph_alloc(int v)
{
  struct graph *G = NULL;
  int i;
  struct node **newNode = NULL;

  if ((G = (struct graph *)malloc(sizeof(struct graph *))) != NULL)
  {
    G->numVert = v;
    G->adjList = (struct node **)malloc(v * sizeof(struct node *));
  }

  /* other stuff */

  return G;
}
```

But valgrind show me this when i compile using `-s --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` and i don't know why

```
==65390== Invalid write of size 8
==65390==    at 0x10985D: graph_alloc (main.c:299)
==65390==    by 0x109801: graph_create (main.c:283)
==65390==    by 0x10925F: main (main.c:75)
==65390==  Address 0x4a429c8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==65390==    at 0x483F7B5: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==65390==    by 0x109830: graph_alloc (main.c:296)
==65390==    by 0x109801: graph_create (main.c:283)
==65390==    by 0x10925F: main (main.c:75)
```

I think the problem is that row becouse without it there is no error

```
G->adjList = (struct node **)malloc(v * sizeof(struct node *));
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Why `G = (struct graph *)malloc(sizeof(struct graph *))`?  What are you trying to allocate here?

Comment: @G.M. i am allocating some space for the graph that had to be returned

Comment: But you are allocating space for a pointer to a graph, which is not enough and causes the invalid writes. Use `G = malloc(sizeof(*G))`.

Comment: @MOehm i can't understand the difference, but it works, can you better explain it?

Comment: @pietroventrucci: `G` has type `struct graph *`. It is a pointer to a `struct graph`. At the address it points to (when it is not a null pointer), there should be space for a `struct graph`. `malloc(sizeof(struct graph *))` allocate space for a `struct graph *`, not for `struct graph`. It is likely not enough space, so your program is broken. To allocate space for one of the things that `G` points to, use the idiom `G = malloc(sizeof *G)`.

Comment: Bottom line: there is a huge, vital, and fundamental difference between *the pointer* versus *the data that the pointer points to*.  When you're first learning about pointers, it is all too easy to overlook this distinction.

Comment: @pietroventrucci: Eric has already explained it, but I've written a "proper" answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to allocate memory for your graph structure here:

```
struct graph *G = NULL;

G = (struct graph *) malloc(sizeof(struct graph *));
```

you allocate memory only for a pointer to the structure, but you need to allocate memory for the thing the pointer points at:

```
struct graph *G = malloc(sizeof(*G));
```

You could also specify the size of the type:

```
struct graph *G = malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
```

but I like the idiom `Type *p = malloc(sizeof(*p))`. The pointer you get from `malloc` is a handle to the memory of the given size you have allocated. It's not the size of the pointer `p` that matters, but the size of what it points to, namely `*p`.

In your case the graph struct is made up of three pointers and an integers, so the graph struct requires more memory than a pointer to the graph struct. That is what causes the invalid writes.

Two observations:

- In C, the cast to `(struct graph *)` is not necessary, because `void *` can be converted to a pointer to something else.
- I find doing both the assignment and the null check in the `if` clause clutters the code and makes it hard to see what's going on. Instead of

  ```
  struct graph *G = NULL;

  if ((G = malloc(sizeof(*G))) != NULL) ...
  ```

  I'd prefer:

  ```
  struct graph *G = malloc(sizeof(*G));

  if (G != NULL) ...
  ```

  which separates the memory allocation from the test for success. It also has way fewer parentheses. `:)` (That's a matter of personal taste perhaps, but my impression is that beginners are very fond of these complicated constructions. Keep it simple.)